# Redirect emails from one user to another

Tags: drupal, email, redirect

Our civicrm adminstrator is suddenly out of action - I need to urgently redirect messages to a new email. I have no idea how to do this, can anyone help
i don't understand computer talk!
Thanks
Ellen

Comment: you need to explain more about why you think this is a civicrm question. pls add more information to your question that might help people help you. is this 'emails that relate to civicrm activities', or 'inbound emails that create civicrm activities' or something else

Comment: Welcome Ellen! It's not clear from your question what sort of emails you're talking about.  If you're not sure how to word it, you may want to consider hiring someone from https://civicrm.org/providers.